# How to parse single quote special charater using Gson library in Scala

Tags: json, scala, gson, special-characters

I am unable to parse json file if values contain single quote and other characters as '()= etc
Hi I have the following Json file:

```json
{
    "config": {
        "inputDFName": "testInput",
        "conditions": "site_type =  'micro'"
    }
}
```

The parser class like

```
case class FilterConfig(inputDFName: String,conditions: String)
```

I am parsing json using below function

```
  def readDataFilter(conf:String): FilterConfig ={
    val gson = new Gson()
    gson.fromJson(conf,classOf[FilterConfig])
  }
```

But return error like : com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException:com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException

but if i remove single quotes and equal to sign its working fine.
Please help here.

Comment: This is not valid Json. I doubt any standard json library will hep you parse this. I have edited the qestion to change it to valid json. Let me know if that is right ?

Comment: @sarveshseri its valid json

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems here.

1. inputDFName in JSON is not matching with testDFName in FilterConfig class.
2. Your JSON structure is different from that of FilterConfig.

I tried to run the code with the above changes and its working fine.

```
case class FilterConfig(inputDFName: String,conditions: String)

import com.google.gson.Gson;

def readDataFiltr(conf:String): FilterConfig ={
  val gson = new Gson()
  gson.fromJson(conf,classOf[FilterConfig])
}
val x = readDataFiltr("{\"inputDFName\": \"testInput\", \"conditions\": \"site_type =  'micro'\"}")

println(x.inputDFName)
println(x.conditions)
```

Please let me know if this is not clear.

Thanks,
Vivek

Comment: the inputDF name was typo issue but the issue i am facing due to equal to sign and single quote